# Search google for domain of company in sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with nearly 4500 company names in column A. I'd like to write a script that searches google for the companies URL and to return that URL in column B

Comment: I have actually built a tool that does this both in sheets and a python script - it searches 8 sources, returns all the values, if 4 or more of those sources have the same url for a row, it considers it a high confidence match, and then allows you to override and pick a winner in the cases where there were less results - if you want to share the list of company names with me I will show the tool, but I am not sharing it fully publicly yet

Comment: Aurielle, thanks for reaching out! This sounds pretty good. Let me try to get some of this stuff into a sheet I can share.

Comment: I left the googledoc url in that chat for you to check out the results

Comment: I can't seem to find it :(

Comment: One sec I'll jump back in

Comment: do you see the link? I just sent it again but your not responding - if you want me to just post the url here - let me know

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the company's official website? I cannot do that, but if you only want a google query, you can use this formula, though I don't think this is what you want : 
`=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://www.google.com/search?q=",A1),A1)`

You might also look at the `GOOGLEFINANCE` function on the formula help page.

Comment: I've been using: 
`=CONCATENATE("https://www.google.com/search?q=",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","+"))`
to at least get me to a search page. Your method is a bit cleaner.